# How can i search table data in silverstripe?

Tags: php, mysql, search, silverstripe

I am new to silver stripe, I tried Zend luncene search, but its not working correctly and its search inside folder documentations, i just want search one  table data by fields and show results. I tried this one but didn't work.

```
 $search = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_Query_Boolean();
```

Is there any good tutorial for search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally this works

```
$hits = ZendSearchLuceneWrapper::find("+(Title: ".$Title.") +(Category: ".$Category.")");
// Convert these into a data array containing pagination info etc
$data = $this->getDataArrayFromHits($hits, $request);

// Display the results page
return $this->owner->customise($data)->renderWith(array('Lucene_results', 'Page'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please define the term "search" as it could mean a few things.

If you wish to search for a record, you could do the following:

DataObject::get("SomeModel", "Field = 'foo'");

SilverStripe is well documented. You can find almost everything you need to know in the docs (http://doc.silverstripe.com/framework/en/) or the forum (http://www.silverstripe.org/forums/).

Hope that helps!